# How to real-time move the range type input's slider using javascript without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, html, input, slider, range

```
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100">
```

I did try the following, but the slider no response.

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('input[type=range]').value = i++;
}, 1000);
```

or impossible?

Comment: working at chrome for me. check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/u7wke/

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with `stepUp` and `stepDown` functions

```
document.getElementById("myslider").stepUp(1);
document.getElementById("myslider").stepDown(1);
```

**working demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/dp6cwoom/

Comment: I have a skider with a react component, it's only moving the slider. not triggering the callback function that's there `onClick`

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
document.querySelector('input[type=range]').value = 30;
--></script>
```

Works ok in Safari4 (Win).
Ensure, your code is after input element or is called inside onload or similar function.

Answer (score 1):

works fine in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/gCSFV/

Comment: thanks. I've updated my question, apologies, my original question was not accurate.

Comment: I have a skider with a react component, it's only moving the slider. not triggering the callback function that's there `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

---

As per the MDC doc on [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector)
Its dsupported by IE8, FF3.5, Chrome1, Safari3.2 and so is input type=range

Syntax

```
element = document.querySelector(selectors);
```

> Returns null if no matches are found;
>   otherwise, it returns the **first**
>   matching element.

Be careful that querySelector returns only first element of the matched ones.
So, `document.querySelector('input[type=range]')` wont be as desirable as something like `document.querySelector('#myrange')`

Comment: thanks. I've updated my question, apologies, my original question was not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way but not very good: to modify the style of input dynamically.

```
var i = 0,
    oRange = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');

setInterval(function(){
    oRage.value = i;
    oRage.style.fontSize = i + 'px';
    i++;
}, 1000);
```