# Trying to move a range input with javascript and also triggering onchange explicity in react

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs

I have a range input with a react component, it's only moving the slider. not triggering the callback function that's there `onChange`

Trigering event explicitly isnt working either for react.

```js
const volumeResetHandler = async () => {
  document.querySelector('input[type=range]').value = 0;//as mentioned by @mathias-s setSlv(0) should also be fine , my concern is the next line
 document.querySelector('input[type=range]').dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
```

```html
<input
 className="slider_input"
 type="range"
 value={slv}
 min="0"
 max="600"
 step="10"
 autoFocus
 onChange={volumeChangeHandler}
/>
<h3 onClick={volumeResetHandler} className="cursor-pointer">Reset</h3>
```

I was expecting `volumeChangeHandler` would get triggered on `document.querySelector('input[type=range]').value = 0;` but it doesn't

All solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911253/how-to-real-time-move-the-range-type-inputs-slider-using-javascript-without-ref/49938796#49938796) suffers from same issue

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396562/change-event-not-firing-after-setting-value-dynamically) does for jquery,  without looking at react or javscript,
it doesnt answer as it is for jquery , changing jquery to js like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50587874/865220) in react isn't working
either.

So there must be something different going on with events in react.

Here is the updated code after trying `useRef` (as suggested by @LãNgọcHải)

```js
import { useRef } from 'preact/hooks'
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
const volumeResetHandler = async () => {
   inputRef.current.value = 0
}
```

```html
<input
 className="slider_input"
 type="range"
 value={slv}
 min="0"
 max="600"
 step="10"
 autoFocus
 onChange={volumeChangeHandler}
 ref={inputRef}
/>
<h3 onClick={volumeResetHandler} className="cursor-pointer">Reset</h3>
```

Inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65625184/865220)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, directly manipulating the DOM will not make React recognize the change. You are calling `volumeChangeHandler` but in a complicated way.

This doesn't work:

```js
  const volumeResetHandler = async () => {
    inputRef.current.value = 0;
    (inputRef.current as any).addEventListener('change', volumeChangeHandler);
    (inputRef.current as any).dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
    // if you replace volumeChangeHandler with another function you will see that
    // it won't get triggered when the actual <input> changes naturally
  }
```

This is how it should be:

```js
  const volumeResetHandler = async () => {
     const valueSetter= Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
         window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,"value")
          .set;                             //Take out the setter function
     valueSetter.call(inputRef.current, 0); //This is how React internally updates state

     inputRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
     //now this event will actually trigger the onchange of the <input>
  }
```

Remember that React uses virtual DOM, direct change of real DOM without state management won't be reconciled so it doesn't trigger the onchange event of the `<input>`

Edit: my code suggestion is written in js, if you're using typescript you might need to change the code a bit to rule out the null/undefined

Comment: Well it isn't working for me,  probably you need to take out `dispatchEvent` as well.

Comment: I understand that first method will fail if I replace `volumeChangeHandler` with another function . I had to do it since `dispatchEvent` wasn't reaching the real `addEventListener` code. Basically I created a parallel ecosystem since the original `addEventListener` is not reachable. But using `valueSetter ` didn't change that , the real `addEventListener` code is still not reachable.

Comment: you still have to use `dispatchEvent` to manually trigger the event of other element in the DOM (make React recognizes the change in DOM). i tested and it worked in JS, so for typescript you might need to do something like using non-null assertion before calling the methods. Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-basic-example-gskwze?file=Test.js) in JS

Comment: Well Fork of your [stackblitz](https://react-basic-example-bz3cqh.stackblitz.io) works with `rangeInput.current.value = 0;` as well.  So my point of using `valueSetter ` or not doesn't make any difference holds. Probably there's something wrong in setup of my project that  `dispatchEvent ` isn't calling  the original `addEventListener `

Comment: @ishandutta2007 you copied the wrong link to your fork, i can't see the code. I tried `rangeInput.current.value = 0` but it does not trigger the `onChange` of the <input>, unless that is not what you want

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-basic-example-bz3cqh?file=Test.js

Comment: @ishandutta2007 what? you should check the logs, i put some `console.log` to show which function gets to run. If you use the `rangeInput.current.value = 0` the log inside `onChange` won't show.

Comment: ok got it.  mybad. I should have logged before claiming it works. So now the point of investigation is what's different in my dev environment. i can't see any difference.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 does it show any error or warning? check if you're using <StrictMode>, it renders components extra time so it could be a problem. Or maybe it's the type check, since `valueSetter` 's type is `PropertyDescriptor | undefined`, you might need to use it like `valueSetter!.call()`

Comment: `!.` in ts is generating the same js code. no warning or error. tell me something isn't this evenlisteners tab supposed to list all attached events. https://imgur.com/xioJ3XT

Comment: `rangeInput.current.onchange` is null for both my proj as well as stackblitz, how does it still work on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

In React, you need to use a [controlled input](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable) to solve this. You should avoid using DOM manipulations like `querySelector` in combination with React for cases like this.

To render a controlled input, pass the `value` prop to it. React will force the input to always have the value you passed.

Use the `onChange` prop to call `setValue` to ensure that the input value always reflects the React state.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10);

  return (
    <input
      type="range"
      value={value} // ...force the input's value to match the state variable...
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} // ... and update the state variable on any edits!
    />
  );
}
```

You can also call `setValue` from other buttons or elements, like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10);

  const volumeResetHandler = () => {
    setValue(0);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="range"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={volumeResetHandler}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

If you have more logic in your `volumeChangeHandler`, that should be run for both `volumeChangeHandler` and `volumeResetHandler`, the idiomatic way to solve this in React would be to move that custom logic into its own function like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10);

  const customChangeHandler = (value) => {
    // Do some custom logic here
    setValue(value);
  };

  const volumeResetHandler = () => {
    customChangeHandler(0);
  };

  const volumeChangeHandler = (e) => {
    customChangeHandler(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="range"
        value={value}
        onChange={volumeChangeHandler}
      />
      <button onClick={volumeResetHandler}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I get what you are saying but in my case the trigger has to come from javascript which was triggered onclick of some other element.

Comment: My concern is not the value setting, my concern is triggering one element's callback from another , Probably I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323279/react-triggering-a-component-method-from-another-component-both-belonging-in)

Comment: @ishandutta2007 maybe you can use [Refs](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs) to trigger the event?

Comment: @LãNgọcHải Yesss I guess that's the correct way, but I can't yet get the code working . `const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)` outsidfe, `inputRef.current.value = 0` in myfunction and corresponding `ref` in html isn't probably enough , probably we need somethig more. If you are sure of the code can you reply with the code please.

Comment: @LãNgọcHải [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71905933/865220) is what I was trying but it is wrong I guess

Comment: @ishandutta2007 try dispatching an event too: `inputRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));` . I don't know if it'll work, i'll look onto it

Comment: @LãNgọcHải it throws error with `dispatchEvent ` is not a function of it. But as per this answer only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65625184/865220) should work.

Comment: Could you explain more about your setup? Do you have a `volumeResetHandler` button in another React component, or is it entirely outside your React application?

Comment: @Mathias-S updated the new code at the bottom.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 i wasn't sure because i only found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42554283/21354514) that worked on class component. Can you simply call the function of the `onChange` or do you have to trigger the change event?
Edit: nevermind just read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59939017/21354514) right under the one i found

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Why do you need to dispatch your own event or update the field value imperatively by directly manipulating the DOM? From your updated code, it looks like both your button/h3 tag and `input` fields are in the same component. If that's the case, it seems like you're thinking about this in the wrong way. Would my updated solution solve your needs? If not, can you give an example of an operation where you really need to use refs here?

Comment: @Mathias-S it does the job but that's like moving away from the problem. by migrating both to a common function. I have to find the bug in what LãNgọcHải suggests.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 It's circumventing the problem altogether, and _that's the point_. Using a common function gives you a simpler component, improving both readability and maintainability. If you don't _need_ to use custom events, then you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @LãNgọcHải you are right but for some reason as per my browser `inputRef.current` is not html dom, but I don't understand why. even [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932213/865220) suggests the same.

Comment: @Mathias-S actually I have lot of animation and other stuff to do for that's I would need access to the event object of Input element so that's why what you suggest is not a proper solution for me. If only setting correct value was the goal then that was fine but i need the event object of the input for many other stuff. For setting value even your previous answer was enough

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with slight modification of what @LãNgọcHải suggested:

```
  const volumeResetHandler = async () => {
    inputRef.current.value = 0;
    (inputRef.current as any).addEventListener('change', volumeChangeHandler);
    (inputRef.current as any).dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
  }
```

Thanks a lot @LãNgọcHải .
Only a small issue I have is I had a logic based on `event.isTrusted==true` which is now `false` for any explicitly triggering event. I would have to find some work around for that. I guess that's what `bubbles` is for, isn't it @LãNgọcHải ?

Comment: `bubbles` is how the event "spread"/ "climb" the DOM tree. For example when you click on a button that is inside a span, the event "bubbles" up from the button to the span and trigger a click event. More info and example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling)

Comment: @LãNgọcHải For my case there is no `bubbles` passed to `volumeChangeHandler ` when actual input range element is moved, that's what why I could change that logic to `(event.isTrusted==true || event.isTrusted==false && event.bubbles==true)` as a workaround.

Comment: the `bubbles` is added because React handles events in higher level in the DOM, event needs to bubble up for React to trigger `onChange` (well, i guess thats why in html it's `onchange` while in React it's `onChange` lol)

Comment: how can I get `isTrusted` to be `true` in such case ?